# How to tell what name RIA Services/EF Model uses for Associations?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-3.0, wcf-ria-services

I'm working on a C#.NET 3.5 WCF RIA Services app and having an issue with my Entity Framework model.

My entity Foo is mapped to a DB table and has a primary key called FooId. My Bar is mapped to a DB view. I've selectively designed this view to generate a composite key in the EF using two of the columns (by making sure they were non-nullable and the others are all nullable. This was done using NULLIF and ISNULL in the view design.)

I'm able to add this view to the model with no problem but I keep running into an issue when I try to map an association between the two. Foo should contain many Bars but I keep getting the following error when I add the association:

> Unable to retrieve AssociationType for
>   association 'FK_Bar_Foo'

According to [this page](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Creating-applications-with-.NET-RIA-Service-Part-3-Adding-DomainService-class.aspx), it looks like this might work if I can properly name the association (since RIA Services looks for specific names.) I've tried several variants of names that match the pattern of other associations with no success. Does anyone know if there's a place I can look to find out what name it's looking for?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found a workaround to the issue [here](http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/08/12/entity-framework-creating-a-model-using-views-instead-of-tables/). The problem with this solution is that you have to repeat it every time the model is updated, which just won't work for me. It appears the current version of the EF doesn't support this type of relation.

The solution I finally went with was to redesign the client to independently call the service and request an entity collection by passing the primary key (FooId) of my Foo type. It's not the best approach (and requires a lot more manual coding) but it does the job. I hope Entity Framework version 4 solves this limitation.